# Preview a JTextArea before printing

Tags: java, swing, printing, jtextarea

How do you offer a preview of a `JTextArea` in a `JDialog` before performing the print operation? The print dialog does not provide this option!

Comment: don't exactly understand your question, please clarify or provide some code.

Comment: @user681159 I have a JTextArea full of text and I want to show a dialog where the user can see the contents before printing (but cannot modify).

Comment: please add that to the question.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `TextComponentPrintable.getPrintable(textArea, null, null)` and use print() method passing Graphics of JPanel to render print view.

There is also solution for JEditorPane http://java-sl.com/JEditorPanePrinter.html

Answer (score -1):

The OP hasn't fully specified this but the comment suggests that he/she wants the user to see what is in the JTextArea before they actually print.

You can do this by making a simple JOptionPane.

`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"your contents","your title",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);`

If this isn't suffice, you can make your own JDialog by making a class and extending JDialog.

`public class dialog extends JDialog{}`

Check out: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

for more information.

Comment: `showMessageDialog` .. That should probably be a `showConfirmDialog` for a print preview, with options to either print or cancel.

Comment: -1 for a) extending (instead of using) JDialog, b) disrespecting java naming conventions

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is with extending? If someone wanted to add more functionality then they can.. and what naming conventions am I disrespecting?

Comment: You already answered the first part of your question yourself: JDialog is-a container - adding components already _is_ his main functionality, nothing new involved :-) As to naming conventions, simply read the corresponding chapter in the tutorial you linked to and compare with the code snippet you posted